# Using CSV to Post Data To MySQL Database PHP

Tags: php, csv, mysqli

I'm a little stuck here and need a little advise. I'm trying to pull the data from a csv file, then push it to a MySQL database. I have my database set up with 6 fields first being the `id` which is set as the A_I for each entry then the following 5 are simply text titles for the data in my csv.

**CSV Example:**

Title1,Title2,Title3,Title4,Title5,

Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4,Data5,

**Database Example:**

ID: 1

Title1: Data1

Title2: Data2

Title3: Data3

Title4: Data4

Title5: Data5

So ideally, I'm trying to ignore the first 5 `,` in the csv as they are just titles then after that each csv has a multiple of 5 `,` which is the data entries. However where I'm getting stuck is I'm not sure how I can simply get this data and `INSERT` it to the SQL database where each 5 `,` is entered under each field in the database. I think I've explained that the best I can.

This is how I'm pulling the data from my database

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>Title1</tr>
            <tr>Title2</tr>
            <tr>Title3</tr>
            <tr>Title4</tr>
            <tr>Title5</tr>

            <?php
                include "php/db.php";

                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                } 


                $sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);

                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    // output data of each row
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {                    
                        echo '<tr>'
                                .'<td>'.$row["title1"].'</td>'
                                .'<td>'.$row["title2"].'</td>'
                                .'<td>'.$row["title3"].'</td>'
                                .'<td>'.$row["title4"].'</td>'
                                .'<td>'.$row["title5"].'</td>'
                            .'</tr>';
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "0 results";
                }
                $conn->close();
            ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Just a little stuck on how I can `INSERT` from a csv file that is already uploaded.

**EDIT**

As Karsten Koop has stated in the comments, to try using `fgetcsv` which has outputted the following data:

> 5 fields in line 1:
>
> Title1
>
> Title2
>
> Title3
>
> Title4
>
> Title5
>
> 5 fields in line 2:
>
> Data1
>
> Data2
>
> Data3
>
> Data4
>
> Data5

Using the following code:

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("docs/mycsv1.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Now the question is how would I go about doing a `INSERT` to my database with this data (bearing in mind that some files have line 2, 3, or even 4 but again they all have 5 fields still?

Comment: Have a look at [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php), it returns the columns of one row in an array, and handles all the corner cases like quoted strings containing the field separator.

Comment: Regarding the titles, you should simply ignore the first row, not the first 5 columns

Comment: @KarstenKoop Thanks for the help here, I've added an update to the post using the resources you've provided. Just need a little guidance on post the data to the database now.

Comment: Does this mean the data you want to write can be found in columns in the CSV, as opposed to each row containing one record? What are the columns in your database?

Comment: This is the csv file that I'm using https://drive.google.com/file/d/10rB4Xk2JHNbHHqidjHpUvDvsR7BofvN_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The columns in the database are: `id`, `title1`, `title2`, `title3`, `title4`, `title5`